# Home movie database software

Tags: windows, video, database

I am looking for (preferably open-source) software for Windows XP that will allow me to keep track of all our self-made videos. My parents should be able to operate it, so we would like it to have a simple interface. Our tapes have recordings of one or more events. We would like to store the location of the event(s) and the people in the event(s). This doesn't have to be automated, we can enter these manually. We have too many tapes to store the videos on our computer, so it shouldn't be a tagging program for movies.

Does anyone know a software program that offers these capabilities?

Answer (score 3):

[**Eric's Movie DB**](http://www.emdb.tk/)

> EMDB is a small utility to keep track of your DVD collection. With an automatic import from the database of IMDB, export to csv, text or complete website, thumbnail cover preview, a loan tracker, search function and multi-language user interface. EMDB is written in C++ using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and doesn't need a .NET framework or any other external libraries. And best of all... it's free!

Comment: Advantages: Free, available for Windows XP. Disadvantages: No way to store multiple events on one tape, no way to annotate events with custom locations. Summary: this software is really made for commercial movies and not for home-videos.

Comment: This is cool :)

Answer (score 0):

See [Gentibus CD](http://www.gentibus.com/).

It works well for all file types and has a good and quick search function (that you can see in the image below):

[image]